# vb.net file watch returns an incorrect filename

Tags: .net, vb.net, filesystemwatcher

I am attempting to use the VB.Net FileSystemWatcher class to watch a folder for the creation of Excel files. I do get a response when a .xls file is created in the folder, but am having a problem with the below code:

```
Private Sub AddWatch()

Dim watch As New FileSystemWatcher

        AddHandler watch.Changed, AddressOf FileChange
        watch.Filter = "*.*"
        watch.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
        watch.Path = "C:\Documents and Settings\my.user\Desktop\testing"
        watch.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

    Private Sub FileChange(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)

        Debug.Print("changetype is: " & e.ChangeType.ToString & ", path is: " & e.FullPath.ToString)
    End Sub
```

When I create a text file in this folder, I get back the proper filename("C:\Documents and Settings\my.user\Desktop\testing\foo.txt"). However, when I save an Excel file into the folder, the path is still correct, but the filename is garbage (differs each time even with the same filename, always 8 characters like "C:\Documents and Settings\my.user\Desktop\testing\DE0B5800".) Can't find a thing on this searching Google or here, and MSDN as usual is little help. Anyone run across this before or know where I can find more information?

Comment: looks like Excel is first saving a temp file?

Comment: sounds like a temp file that excel is writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814068

In summary:

> When Excel saves a file, Excel follow
>   these steps:
>
> 1. **Excel creates a randomly named temporary file (for example, Cedd4100
>      with no file name extension) in the
>      destination folder that you specified
>      in the Save As dialog box.** The whole
>      workbook is written to the temporary
>      file.
> 2. If changes are being saved to an existing file, Excel deletes the
>      original file.
> 3. Excel renames the temporary file. Excel gives the temporary file
>      the file name that you specified (such
>      as Book1.xls) in the Save As dialog
>      box.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Looks like I'll be writing my own.